# Opencart Second Store 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: php, opencart

I create a new store in a different domain an opencart. this is my following steps as well :

```
system > setting > add new store
```

my second store URL : http://acropulse.com/

i put on the complete details as well. after I open the second store below errors :

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: new, fresh instalation ?

Comment: @Dilek. opencart already installed. but new store creation issue

Comment: There are tons of modifications to cause that error, mostly urls in htaccess, see the documentation Creating a Multi-Store: http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/administration/multi-store/

Comment: yes, I already follow the above steps. but it's nothing works for me